# How to stop data tables overlapping each other in R Shiny Dashboard?

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm having problems with a dashboard I'm creating where I require 2 tables to be side by side. This part is fine, but when the window opens at the default size (or if the user makes it smaller than the necessary width to display the full tables), the data tables overlap each other, until the user makes the window sufficiently narrow so that the nav bar disappears and the second data table moves down onto the next row.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and is there a way to stop this?

I've reproduced this with some example code.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

ui <- dashboardPage( 
  skin = "blue",
  dashboardHeader(title = "Test"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    width = 250,
    collapsed = FALSE,
    sidebarMenu(
      id = "tabs",
      menuItem("Tables",tabName="tab",icon=icon("car")))
    ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        "tab",
        fluidPage(
          fluidRow(
            column(width = 4,
                   h4("TABLE 1"),
                   DTOutput("table1")),
            column(width = 4,
                   h4("TABLE 2"),
                   DTOutput("table2"))
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  table1 <- head(iris)[1:2]
  table2 <- head(iris)[3:5]
  
  output$table1 <- DT::renderDT({
    datatable(table1,
              escape=FALSE,
              rownames=TRUE,
              selection ='none',
              options = list(
                dom ='t',
                paging = FALSE,
                searcing = FALSE,
                filtering = FALSE,
                ordering = FALSE)
              )
    })
  
  output$table2 <- DT::renderDT({
    datatable(table2,
              escape=FALSE,
              rownames=TRUE,
              selection ='none',
              options = list(
                dom ='t',
                paging = FALSE,
                searcing = FALSE,
                filtering = FALSE,
                ordering = FALSE)
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Ideally I would like the column widths to adjust automatically as required (even if it means that part of the text is covered up - think of an excel spreadsheet where the text is too long, and there's something in the next cell so it just get's cut off). At any rate, I don't want the tables to overlap, and they should stay within the column boundaries.

Comment: Use datatable option `scrollX = TRUE`

Comment: @YBS Thanks, this does work, and I may have to settle for this solution. However, ideally I would like the columns to just adjust their width automatically to accomodate for this without creating a scroll bar with the second table moving below the first when the page window width is too small (which it does eventually anyway, but not before it overlaps).